# How to show Woocommerce custom fields (select options) front-end?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have created a Woocommerce custom field using the code below.

```
woocommerce_wp_select(   
  array(    
    'id' => '_select',    
    'label' => __( 'My Select Field', 'woocommerce' ),    
    'options' => array(
         'one' => __( 'Option 1', 'woocommerce' ),
         'two' => __( 'Option 2', 'woocommerce' ),
         'three' => __( 'Option 3', 'woocommerce' )
         )    
      ) 
   );
```

I was able to show the value front-end.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta (get_the_ID(),'_select',true); ?>
```

But what I wanted to achieve is to display @front-end the select options field not the value.

Any inputs would very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_wp_select` can only be used in WP Admin since file `wc-meta-box-functions.php` is only loaded there, in frontend you will get errors.

You could try including that file but it may (or may not) have more dependencies that are not loaded on a typical frontend request:

```
include_once( 'wc-meta-box-functions.php' );
```

(Note - I took this line directly from WooCommerce's code base, you will need to append a relative path to the file name above)

You would also need a handler that will save field data on submit, I doubt values will be picked up automatically by WooCommerce when fields are used in this way.

If using a plugin is not a problem, you could try [WooCommerce Custom Fields & Product Add-ons](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742) or some other plugin that does this job auto-magically.